# Issue with a DateTimePicker and how to pass the date selected to another function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, datepicker

I don't use often js script but to finish my project i need to resolve this issue. I'm using DateTimePicker from https://github.com/nehakadam/DateTimePicker .

After initialize the calendar, i can select a date and the date is showing in the calendar input.
But after that i don't know how to retrieve and to send the date selected (for example 02-01-2021) to another script in further in my html file. I have a variable called :

```
var dataSource2 = "../testcanvas/data/Multi_band_01-01-2021.tif";
```

The date selected must change the dataSource2 variable (so in Multi_band_02-01-2021.tif).

Here is my code for the calendar:

```
        <script>

            $(document).ready(function()
                {$("#dtBox")
                .DateTimePicker({
                    addEventHandlers: function()
                    {
                        var dtPickerObj = this;

                        $("#datePicker .pickerButton").click(function(e)
                        {
                            dtPickerObj.on("change", function(e){ console.log(e.date); })
                            alert("test");
                        });                 
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>
```

None of the alert and the console.log is triggered. I don't know what the problem as this stage.

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Usually when a developer enables user to pass a function to a property, the values you get are from this callback.

Give it a shot using this, `.DateTimePicker({ addEventHandlers:console.log, ... })`

So my suggestion is to pass the console.log function to the addEventHandlers, this way when the handler is called, it will print in the console all the arguments passed to the callback which are the variables you have access to. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

ok i found a solution :

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var oDTP, dDate, dTime, dDateTime,
            sDateFormat = "";
            $(document).ready(function()
                {$("#dtBox")
                .DateTimePicker({

                    dateFormat: "dd-MM-yyyy",
                                                
                    buttonClicked: function(sButtonType, oElement)
                    {
                        oDTP = this;

                        if(sButtonType === "SET")
                        {
                            datex=oDTP.getDateTimeStringInFormat("Date", "dd-MM-yyyy");
                            var dataSource2="../testcanvas/data/Multi_band_"+datex+".tif";
                            updateChart(dataSource2)
                        }                                
                    }

                });
            });
        </script>
```

Thanks Caio Koiti for your help ! :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).